# How i can translate the following datatype defined in Haskell to VB .net?

Tags: vb.net, haskell

The following datatype defined in Haskell is:

```hs
type Tag = String
type Content = String
data HTML = B Tag Content | R Tag HTML
```

But in VB.Net i can't define recursive structures. And i don't know how to define the "|" that is a some kind of "or"/"union" in Haskell.

Comment: Closely related: [*How can I simulate Haskell's “Either a b” in Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9975836/2751851)

Comment: Why can't you define recursive structures? From a few seconds Googling that looks [pretty trivial](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/4647/a-simple-binary-tree-implementation-with-vb-net) to me.

Comment: Your `Tag` type isn't actually used in your example.

Comment: `HTML` doesn't have a valid definition; you reuse the `Tag` data constructor. It's also not very interesting; it doesn't define a tree of `Content`, it just allows you to wrap a `Content` value in an arbitrary number of wrappers. As such, it's isomorphic to `type HTML' = (Int, Content)`.

Comment: Sorry, true. I have added B and R data constructor.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks! I haven't tried with class yet. The problem is when i define a structure. It can't be recursive

Comment: @Isalvatore .Net structures can't be recursive, classes can. [Always use classes instead of structures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx) unless you _really_ know what you're doing. Structures are passed as value types, and flattened wherever they are used; a recursive structure would be flattened into itself and either be empty or have infinite size. [Variance on structures doesn't work correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type).

Answer (score 1):

The [standard OO way of doing this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973803.aspx) would be

```
Public MustInherit Class HTML
    Public Tag as String
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits HTML

    Public Content as String
End Class

Public Class R
    Inherits HTML

    Public HTML as HTML
End Class
```

This isn't the same as the Haskell datatype. Besides possibly being `null`, someone could define another class that's neither `B` nor `R`

```
Public Class TrickedYou
    Inherits HTML
End Class
```

There's [another way to express sum types in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18426577/414413) that matches Haskell's sum types up to `null`s. It uses generics and is fairly alien to OO programming; the closest OO design pattern is a visitor, which almost gets a sum type right. The visitor OO pattern doesn't get the generic return type right.

Comment: To actually use this you need to do a typecase/downcast with is ugly af.  If you add a method corresponding to the appropriate fold operation or to a single layer of pattern matching to the base class, then this problem and the first one you mention are both solved.  While new subclasses like `TrickedYou` can be added, they will be forced to observationally behave (modulo side-effects and downcasting) like the modeled algebraic data type.

Comment: @DerekElkins That's what the last linked answer is. I have no desire to ever write generic code with variance markings in VB.Net.